# Correcting my Linux $PATH of multiple rbenv paths

Tags: ruby, unix, rbenv

I am fresh to Linux Ubuntu and I have messed up my Ruby on Rails install.
Therefore, I uninstalled Ruby and attempted to follow the [rbenv installation.](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions)
However, I am getting this stack trace:

```
martin@martyux:~$ curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: multiple
  You seem to have multiple rbenv installs in the following locations.
  Please pick just one installation and remove the others.

  /home/martin/.rbenv/bin/rbenv
  /usr/bin/rbenv
  /bin/rbenv

Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: not found
  The directory `/home/martin/.rbenv/shims' must be present in PATH for rbenv to work.
  Please run `rbenv init' and follow the instructions.

Checking `rbenv install' support: /home/martin/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/rbenv-install (ruby-build 20210119)
Counting installed Ruby versions: none
  There aren't any Ruby versions installed under `/home/martin/.rbenv/versions'.
  You can install Ruby versions like so: rbenv install 2.2.4
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: OK
```

I am assuming that there's instances of rbenv I attempted to install earlier and somehow is still linked to $PATH. I didn't find anyone with this exact issue and I am not competent at navigating the Unix shell yet, so I would appreciate some thorough help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you got rbenv to end up in `/bin/rbenv` and `usr/bin/rbenv`, but for what I can see from their installation guide you only need `~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv`.

Assuming you use bash, I think these are all added to your `$PATH` in `~/.bashrc`. You should find something like:

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:/bin/rbenv"
```

And

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/rbenv"
```

You can remove those lines. To clean up properly you can also remove the rbenv installs they refer to as well.

Lastly, as the error message says, you want to run `rbenv init` after doing this to create the `shims` folder.

Comment: I've removed these lines and removed rbenv, ruby-build and the ruby version that came with it. I made sure NONE of these were linked to $PATH, doing the curl command. Yet, doing a fresh install of rbenv gives me the same issue every time. Do I need to purge any additional files in my /usr/bin or /bin/, perhaps?

Comment: Also are you sure the install shouldn't be going into /usr/bin, not /bin/?

Comment: If you keep getting the same error, somewhere in your system those invalid paths are added to your path.

Comment: Looks like I used both the Package Manager installation AND the Github installation provided on rbenv's repository documentation. Fixed it by deleting all Ruby-related files and then following the installation guide more closely.

Comment: how did you delete all ruby related files?

Comment: @cratag I simply scanned manually through /usr/bin and /bin/ for all files with a Ruby logo or .rb or similar endings. Was probably a hack, but worked.

Comment: I've gone through removing all my ruby files multiple times, and I'm still getting the multiple rbenv in path error.

Comment: @the_meter413 then your path is still referring to multiple rbenv instances. You can echo your path to see what's in there: `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

I did not have `export PATH="$PATH:/bin/rbenv"` and `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/rbenv"` in my `~/.bashrc`

I just ran

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby

sudo apt-get purge rbenv
```

and then

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```

showed only one path.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a `~/.gemrc` with  `gem: --user-install` in it, then the gemrc will configure rbenv to install gems in `~/.gem`, which is not how rbenv is expecting it - rbenv wraps the gem call via a shim, so you can try rename / remove ~/.gemrc and then try run `gem install <whatever>` again and it should all work